# How do I use group by in GraphQL, and is there a way to use date functions inside a query filter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm new to GraphQL and am struggling.

I have a set of matches, and would like to group them based on the year a match was played.

```
type Match @model @searchable {
  id: ID!
  playedOn: AWSDate! 
  playerId: ID!
  setsWon: Int!
  ...
}
```

I'm using the `@searchable` directive to have AWS generate some aggregate functionality, and I can write a query like

```
query MyQuery {
  searchMatches(filter: {playerId: {eq: "1"}}, 
  aggregates: {field: playedOn, name: "year", type: terms}) {
    
    aggregateItems {
      result {
        ... on SearchableAggregateBucketResult {
          __typename
          buckets {
            doc_count
            key
          }
        }
      }
      name
    }
    total
  }
}
```

This is where I'd like to write something like `aggregates: {field: GetYear(playedOn), name: "year", type: terms}) {` to get the year, instead of on the full date, which is useless.

I'm happy if I can get that far, though, ultimately, I'd like to aggregate other data within the sum of setsWon etc., and totaling up the number of matches played for all years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Global Secondary Index with `yearTheMatchWasPlayed` as the primary key.

```
   type Match @model {
      id: ID!
      playedOn: AWSDate! 
      playerId: ID!
      setsWon: Int!
      yearTheMatchWasPlayed
        @index(
          name: "yearTheMatchWasPlayed"
          queryField: "yearTheMatchWasPlayed"
        )
    }
```

Learn more about indexing from AWS Amplify [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=indexing%20aws%20graphql&oq=indexing%20aws%20graphql&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l2.2608j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).
Test your JSON expectations with AWS AppSync before writing the front-end solutions.